# Pandas: Derive a days, hours, minutes, seconds timestamp from available data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

With this expected data, I am trying to see if I can return the following result:

```
#expected result
'12.22:05:38.3911208'
```

```
# mwe
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'wrong_ts': '1970-01-13T22:05:38.391+0000',
                   'minutes': 18605,
                   'seconds': 38,
                   'ms': 391,
                   'expected': '12.22:05:38.3911208'})
```

This gets me fairly close, but not quite:

```
df['duration'] = df['minutes'].astype(str) + 'm ' + df['seconds'].astype(str) + 's ' +  df['ms'].astype(str) + 'ms'

pd.to_timedelta(df.duration)
# 12 days 22:05:38.391000
```

Comment: it seems your expected "timestamp" is just the 'wrong_ts' minus 1970-01-01 midnight, is that correct?

Comment: Indeed, but it does not quite get me the last 3 digits in the micro/miliseconds(?) `391000` vs `391208`

Comment: I don't see those 208 microseconds anywhere in your example's minutes, seconds or ms ?

Comment: That's right. I am wondering what might explain that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. Using `to_pytimedelta` and converting the time to string.
Then from the resulting string, split and get the days and time in the required format.

```
time_delta = pd.to_timedelta(df.duration)

my_date = time_delta.dt.to_pytimedelta().astype(str)
split_time = my_date[0].split(',')
days = split_time[0]
time = split_time[1].strip()
print(days.split('days')[0].strip() + '.' + time)
```

**Output:**

```
12.22:05:38.391000
```

Comment: Indeed this is great, I am wondering about the difference in the last 3 digits in the micro/miliseconds (?) where the output is `391000` vs `391208`; I am not sure what could account for that.